# Django Crispy form set model field as required

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a modelform in which I want to set required attribute to True for email validation

field:-`email`

```
class RegisterMyBuisinessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = '/registermybuisness/'
        Field('email', type='email')
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit',css_class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-square c-btn-bold c-btn-uppercase"))
        super(RegisterMyBuisinessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        model = RegistermyBusiness
        fields = ['name','email', 'org_name', 'contact','business_description','store_address','message','store_landmark','business_type','city']
```

I tried

```
self.fields['email'].required=True
```

this resulted in class RegisterMyBuisinessForm doesnot have fields error

Comment: Note that you've mispelled `Business` in the name of the form class and the `form_action`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can alter `self.fields['email']` in the `__init__` method. You need to call `super()` first.

```
class RegisterMyBuisinessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        super(RegisterMyBuisinessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        ...
```